# Minipage in Latex failing to compile

Tags: latex

I want to put a table and figure above/below one another in my article tex file as they are related. Until now it has worked in this document but suddenly it isn't working and I can't compile in Overleaf. Please help.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{1\textwidth}

\centering
\captionof{table}{Best Case Scenario A IC values when synthesis, desiccation (and algae collection) have been excluded from the system.}
\label{tab:BestA_synthANDdesiccation_excluded}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llcc@{}}
\toprule
IC     & Unit         & Total (no collection) & Total (with collection) \\ \midrule
CC     & kg   CO2 eq  & -1.1E+03                                  & -7.0E+02                \\
Ecotox & CTUe         & 2.1E+02                                   & 1.4E+04                 \\
HTnc   & CTUh         & 6.9E-08                                   & 1.4E-05                 \\
PM     & disease inc. & 3.7E-07                                   & 1.0E-05                 \\
RUf    & MJ           & 9.3E+01                                   & 5.6E+03                 \\
RUm    & kg Sb eq     & 8.0E-06                                   & 3.6E-02                 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Pictures/A_best_nosynANDnodesiccationANDnocollection.png}
    \captionof{figure}{Characterisation of the sub-systems in best-case scenario A when synthesis, desiccation and algae collection have been excluded from the system boundaries. Method: EF 3.0 Method (adapted) V1.00}
    \label{fig:Abest_nosyn_nodesiccation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: minipages needs a width.

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the minipage has an mandatory argument to specify the width, so you'll need

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
```

Some other comments:

- best not specify a file type for your image `\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Pictures/A_best_nosynANDnodesiccationANDnocollection}`. If you have the same image in different formats latex will then include the one best suited for the engine you use to compile your document
- Unless your minipage is in a float environment like `figure` or `table` you want to add `\noindent` before the minipage. Without this there is not enough space in your line to fit a minipage with `\textwidth`
- if you want to have the numbers in your table nicely aligned, have a look at the `siunitx` package

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[b]{1\textwidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Best Case Scenario A IC values when synthesis, desiccation (and algae collection) have been excluded from the system.}
\label{tab:BestA_synthANDdesiccation_excluded}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llcc@{}}
\toprule
IC     & Unit         & Total (no collection) & Total (with collection) \\ \midrule
CC     & kg   CO2 eq  & -1.1E+03                                  & -7.0E+02                \\
Ecotox & CTUe         & 2.1E+02                                   & 1.4E+04                 \\
HTnc   & CTUh         & 6.9E-08                                   & 1.4E-05                 \\
PM     & disease inc. & 3.7E-07                                   & 1.0E-05                 \\
RUf    & MJ           & 9.3E+01                                   & 5.6E+03                 \\
RUm    & kg Sb eq     & 8.0E-06                                   & 3.6E-02                 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \captionof{figure}{Characterisation of the sub-systems in best-case scenario A when synthesis, desiccation and algae collection have been excluded from the system boundaries. Method: EF 3.0 Method (adapted) V1.00}
    \label{fig:Abest_nosyn_nodesiccation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```